# To what extend can passive smoking be dangerous?

Tags: smoking, second-hand-smoke

Recently, I got picked up by a friend's neighbour. His car extremely strongly smells of cigaretts.

Is it bad for your lungs to stay in that car for let's say 15 minutes? Can such a short amount of time being a passive smoker already cause long-term damage? How long would I have to stay in that car to suffer really serious damages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, passive smoking can induce an asthmatic attack and, depending on duration of exposure, harm your lungs. There is also a publication in NEJM from 1999 (http://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJM199903253401204) that shows that passive smoking is associated with a small increase in the risk of coronary heart disease.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you have a link to that publication?

Comment: Here it comes :)

Comment: http://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJM199903253401204